# Crystal Reports: Using a summary field in a Formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that groups the results by ItemCode. The item code can only take on two formats (### and ###AA). I have recoded all these Item codes to just follow the ### format in a variable called Item3. I also created a summary variable by counting the number of distint Item codes - (An item3 code that is 123, could have had 3 distinct original item codes 123, 123AA, and 123BB).

What I need to do is use that distinct count summary field in a formula - something like

```
if (distinctcount({CI_Item.ItemCode}) = 1) then
    "TRUE"
 else
    "FALSE"
```

but this isn't working. All of this will be placed in my group1 footer. Can anyone help?

Comment: your summary variable should appear in your list of report fields.  you can select it from that list and paste it into your formula.

Comment: It didn't but I was able to create a running total. It is working that way. Thank you!!!